# Error Loading Python 3.4

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x

My laptop is installed with Windows 7 64-bit operating system.

Prior to the installation of Python 3.4 using installation file "python-3.4.0.amd64.msi" (downloaded from https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-340/), I have been using Python 2.7. However, I still need Python 2.7 for ABAQUS and hence need to retain it.

After I installed Python 3.4 and added its path to the environmental variables there was a conflict in calling "python" from command prompt. So I re-named python.exe in Python27 and Python34 folder as python27.exe and python34.exe, respectively. Also I added 27 and 34 as suffix to various other files in scripts folder in both version. I doubt if this is the best way to go forward in retaining two versions at the same time. So this is one question for which I would like an answer or a suitable reference.

But after installation of Python 3.4 I am not able to load python.exe, neither directly from folder nor command prompt. I get the following error:

```
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: unable to load the file system codec
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\encodings\__init__.py", line 31, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'codecs'
```

I am not able to uninstall the Python 3.4 from the control panel too. I get the following error when I attempt it:

[image]

I also tried removing the folder and installing the setup again. But still I get the same error.

I would be glad if some of the Python experts to help me resolve this problem.

Comment: Hmm. That doesn't sound good. I don't do Windows, but I suspect you need to totally uninstall the Python 3 stuff, make sure that your Python 2 installation works the way it used to, and then re-install Python 3. BTW, the usual convention is to call Python 2 with the name "python" and call Python 3 "python3". The reason for that is that old stuff that calls the python executable will expect to get Python 2.

Comment: @PM2Ring Okay.. But we would have to rename to "python3" manually for Python 3.4, right? And what about pip, wheel... etc in scripts folder? Do we need to rename that too?

Comment: Your first choice when seeing an error like that should be to repair the installation -- not remove the folder. As to the fatal Python error, first ensure that neither `PYTHONHOME` nor `PYTHONPATH` is defined. As to scripts, the exe wrappers created by pip for entry points are versioned, but not the ones created by setuptools. If you're adding a versioned name, never rename installed files. Create a symbolic link via cmd's `mklink`.

Comment: @eryksun Thanks for your response. In the environment variables I have not defined PYTHONHOME nor PYTHONPATH. But the following value is entered for the system variables- "Path" in the envrionment variable setting: C:\Python34\;C:\Python34\Scripts\;C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Scripts\

Comment: I hope the system `PATH` has more than just those directories in it. As a subset of `PATH` it's fine. It prioritizes the Python 3.4 installation.

Comment: @eryksun Yes. It has more than that. But those are related to different programs. Have you got any idea why this fatal error is still cropping up?